# Extract values from XML in SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2014

Please could someone give some guidance on the most efficient way to extract some values from an XML column? I've tried using substring and charindex within a case statement but this gets really messy and isn't the best performer. I would have thought that there is an XML function which would work better but struggling to find any examples online that use XML anything like this;

```
<pro:Import xmlns:pro="http://thenamespace/">
<pro:Control DatabaseName="varchar" UserName="varchar" Password="varchar" Company="varchar" Version="varchar" ErrorHandlingMode="varchar" />
<pro:Invoice RegisterInvoiceEvenIfParentOrdersAreInvalid="Bool" Tray="Varchar" Template="varchar" Supplier="varchar" SupplierInvoiceNumber="int" InvoiceDate="datetime" GrossValue="decimal" TaxValue="decimal" ImageReference="uniqueidentifier">
    <pro:References>
        <pro:Reference Code="varchar" Value="datetime" />
        <pro:Reference Code="varchar" Value="varchar" />
    </pro:References>
    <pro:ParentOrders>
        <pro:ParentOrder OrderNumber="varchar" />
    </pro:ParentOrders>
    <pro:TaxDetails>
        <pro:Tax Band="varchar" Code="varchar" GrossValue="decimal" TaxValue="decimal" />
    </pro:TaxDetails>
    <pro:Comments>
        <pro:Comment>varchar</pro:Comment>
    </pro:Comments>
</pro:Invoice>
```

The values I want to extract will vary, as will the XML. This is one example but there may be times when the values i want to extract for some XML are not present in others.

**Example:**

There might always be a `Supplier="xxxx"` but not a `SupplierInvoiceNumber="xxxx"` and its position will vary.

For arguments sake though, lets say for this exercise i just want to pull out

`Supplier="varchar"` & `SupplierInvoiceNumber="int"`

Thanks all :)

~D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML misses the closing final tag...

> I've tried using substring and charindex within a case statement but this gets really messy and isn't the best performer.

It is a **very bad idea** to try to read from XML on string level...

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<pro:Import xmlns:pro="http://thenamespace/">
  <pro:Control DatabaseName="varchar" UserName="varchar" Password="varchar" Company="varchar" Version="varchar" ErrorHandlingMode="varchar" />
  <pro:Invoice RegisterInvoiceEvenIfParentOrdersAreInvalid="Bool" Tray="Varchar" Template="varchar" Supplier="varchar" SupplierInvoiceNumber="int" InvoiceDate="datetime" GrossValue="decimal" TaxValue="decimal" ImageReference="uniqueidentifier">
    <pro:References>
      <pro:Reference Code="varchar" Value="datetime" />
      <pro:Reference Code="varchar" Value="varchar" />
    </pro:References>
    <pro:ParentOrders>
      <pro:ParentOrder OrderNumber="varchar" />
    </pro:ParentOrders>
    <pro:TaxDetails>
      <pro:Tax Band="varchar" Code="varchar" GrossValue="decimal" TaxValue="decimal" />
    </pro:TaxDetails>
    <pro:Comments>
      <pro:Comment>varchar</pro:Comment>
    </pro:Comments>
  </pro:Invoice>
</pro:Import>';
```

--Clean

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://thenamespace/')
SELECT @xml.value('(/Import/Invoice/@Supplier)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Supplier
      ,@xml.value('(/Import/Invoice/@SupplierInvoiceNumber)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SupplierInvoiceNumber
```

--Lazy

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//@Supplier)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Supplier
      ,@xml.value('(//@SupplierInvoiceNumber)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SupplierInvoiceNumber
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I had tried with xml.Value but i was trying to read it like this, based on something i found online, (/ns:Import/ns:Invoice)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as 'Supplier' and this returned the comments instead. Thanks for the really speedy response!